# Delete an Item in a Nested Object in Redux State

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, redux, react-redux-form

I am trying to delete an item in a nested state but I have no idea how to implement that.

data structure

```
{
 property: {
  "_id" : "52",
  "name" : "random",
  "options" : ["item1", "item2", "item3"]
 }
}
```

to delete a property, I am just making a comparison like this and it is working

```
property: state.property.filter(data => data._id !== action.propertyId),
```

but the problem is when I want to delete an item of options array, how can I delete an item and compare the values

Comment: What's your expected output? I mean what result are you expecting? What do you want to do?

Comment: What you are trying to achieve here? You are using ```.filter``` which is method of array. And your ```property``` is object. ```.filter``` can only be used with array

Comment: @ArchitGarg i want to delete an item of array option, the scenario is when i click on a button, the item of the array must be deleted but in my current scenario, i must refresh the page to see the data change

Comment: @AbhinabRajopadhyaya the filter method is working as expected when i want to delete the property, and i am using it here just to illustrate my exemple

Comment: @Beloved You can do something like - state.property.data.filter(data => data !== action.dataId)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you're looking for below...

```js
let state = {
  "property": {
    "_id": "52",
    "name": "random",
    "options": ["item1", "item2", "item3"]
  }
}

state.property.options = state.property.options.filter(ele => ele !== "item2")

console.log(state)
```

Comment: it is not working, it gives me the error TypeError: state.forEach is not a function

Comment: What is the type of `state`?

Comment: Updated answer again

Comment: the type  of state is an object, the object ''property" that has 3 fields {_id, name and options which is an array} and i want to delete a single item of options, not the entire object property